# scala view filter not lazy?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

While trying to understand the differences between streams, iterators, and views of collections, I stumbled upon the following strange behavior.

Here the code (map and filter simply print their input and forward it unchanged):

```
object ArrayViewTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val array = Array.range(1,10)

    print("stream-map-head: ")
    array.toStream.map(x => {print(x); x}).head

    print("\nstream-filter-head: ")
    array.toStream.filter(x => {print(x); true}).head

    print("\niterator-map-head: ")
    array.iterator.map(x => {print(x); x}).take(1).toArray

    print("\niterator-filter-head: ")
    array.iterator.filter(x => {print(x); true}).take(1).toArray

    print("\nview-map-head: ")
    array.view.map(x => {print(x); x}).head

    print("\nview-filter-head: ")
    array.view.filter(x => {print(x); true}).head
  }
}
```

And its output:

```
stream-map-head: 1
stream-filter-head: 1
iterator-map-head: 1
iterator-filter-head: 1
view-map-head: 1
view-filter-head: 123456789    // <------ WHY ?
```

Why does filter called on a view process the whole array?
I expected that the evaluation of filter is driven only once by calling head, just as in all other cases, in particular just as in using map on view.

Which insight am I missing ?

(Mini-side-question for a comment, why is there no head on an iterator?)

**edit:**
The same strange behavior (as here for `scala.Array.range(1,10)`) is achieved by `scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.range(1,10)`, `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.range(1,10)`, and `scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.newBuilder.append("123456789")`.
*However, for all other mutable collections, and all immutable collections, the filter on the view works as expected and outputs `1`.*

Comment: (mini-side-answer) if you wanted to get first element of iterator you would have to advance it using `next` and calling it e.g. twice would be problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the `head` uses `isEmpty`

```
trait IndexedSeqOptimized[+A, +Repr] extends Any with IndexedSeqLike[A, Repr] { self =>
...
override /*IterableLike*/
def head: A = if (isEmpty) super.head else this(0)
```

And `isEmpty` uses `length`

```
trait IndexedSeqOptimized[+A, +Repr] extends Any with IndexedSeqLike[A, Repr] { self =>
  ...
  override /*IterableLike*/
  def isEmpty: Boolean = { length == 0 }
```

The implementation of `length` is used from `Filtered` which loops through the whole array

```
trait Filtered extends super.Filtered with Transformed[A] {
  protected[this] lazy val index = {
    var len = 0
    val arr = new Array[Int](self.length)
    for (i <- 0 until self.length)
      if (pred(self(i))) {
        arr(len) = i
        len += 1
      }
    arr take len
  }
  def length = index.length
  def apply(idx: Int) = self(index(idx))
}
```

The `Filtered` trait is only used when calling `filter`

```
protected override def newFiltered(p: A => Boolean): Transformed[A] =
 new { val pred = p } with AbstractTransformed[A] with Filtered
```

This is why is happens when using `filter` and not when using `map`

Comment: Thanks for this trace! Indeed, this problem seems to occur only for the `IndexedSeq` trait (see my edited post). Do you agree that this way how it is implemented is a stupid waste of performance and may be denoted as a bug? Ignoring any internal necessity: it sounds absolutely unnecessary to me to compute the length of an array by counting its elements individually - indeed O(1) access to the length of an array is a crucial property of arrays, and in fact the information on the array length *is* there - it is simply not read by filter.

Comment: I agree performance is not optimised for your situation. I don't know if this is a tradeoff or could be prevented. Maybe you can ask https://gitter.im/scala/contributors

Comment: To clarify: Scala isn't computing the length of an array by counting its elements. It is computing the length of a view by counting its elements, but a view of an array isn't an array.

Answer (score 3):

I think it has to do that `Array` is a mutable indexed sequence. And it's view is also a mutable collection :) So when it creates a view it creates an index that maps between original collection and filtered collection. And it doesn't really make sense to create this index lazily, because when someone will request the ith element than the whole source array may be traversed anyway. It is still lazy in a sense that this index is not created until you call `head`. Still this is not explicitly stated in scala documentation, and it looks like a bug at first sight.

For the mini side question, I think the problem with `head` on iterator is that people expect `head` to be pure function, namely you should be able to call it n times and it should return the same result each time. And iterator is inherently mutable data structure, which by contract is only traversable once. This may be overcomed by caching the first element of the iterator, but I find this to be very confusing.

Comment: actually arrays `view` is lazy in `map` function. why

Comment: Because you don't need to rebuild the index between mapped view and source view. Also I'm not sure if mapped view is not a copy... Very confusing